# Does GreenDao updates the tableDao's database session, by updating table record by executing sql

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

```
QueryBuilder<Person> queryBuilder = this.queryBuilder();
WhereCondition whereCondition = Properties.Id.eq(10);
try {
  // Following line fetches list of person with id 10, which has name BBBB.
  List<Person> PersonsList = queryBuilder.where(whereCondition).list();
  if(PersonsList != null && PersonsList.size() > 0){
     Log.e("Fetched Person1--->", PersonsList.get(0).getName());

     // To update record using query like this.
     String updateQuery = "UPDATE PERSON SET NAME = 'AAAA' WHERE id = 10";
     personDao.execSQL(updateQuery);
  }

  // Again fetching that person record list of id 10.
  List<Person> PersonsList1 = queryBuilder.where(whereCondition).list();
  if(PersonsList1 != null && PersonsList1.size() > 0){
     // Here i am expecting result to be person name as AAAA
     Log.e("Fetched Person2--->", PersonsList1.get(0).getName());
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

New updated name wont get reflected on same record.
This is the code while fetching record using dao and performing sql update operation on it.

Or is there any way in GreenDao, that we can update record using where condition.

Comment: ... what is your question?

Comment: when updating fetched record using "Update " query, and again fetching that result using PersonDao as PersonList1 as above does not reflect the updated changes.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to be more explicit there.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in methods of greendao to modify your data instead of raw SQL-queries:

```
List<Person> PersonsList = queryBuilder.where(whereCondition).list();
if (PersonList != null) {
    for (Person p : PersonList) {
        p.setName("AAAA");
        p.update();
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to do the update with a single query, you can use your query.
Probably greendao caches your results and thus isn't really querying the db a second time in your test.

Use this to clear your session-cache.

```
DaoSession.clear();
```

Nevertheless I don't recommend updates like this, as it may have stronger impact on your performance than using the ORM-way as all cached entities have to be queried again.

Comment: Yes, but in this case 2 queries will get fired, first to fetch and then 2nd in update method.

Comment: @VishalKharat That's true. You asked about how to update the entities. In fact the overhead will be ignoreable in most cases. If you want to do it in a single call see my update.

Comment: I was not getting the updated values from db. `DaoSession.clear();` solved my problem thanks. **Is it ok to call `daoSession.clear()` everytime my activity restarts?**
 bcoz if I dont it won't give me the latest results. @AlexS

Comment: @VJVishalJogiya Seems you are updating your data by other means than the greendao-entities. First you should try to avoid this! If that's not possible `daoSession.clear()` can be used. Depending on your app your performance will decrease, because of the repeated queries against the database.

Answer (score 2):

Green DAO does not support Updates. You need to update using entities. If you do stuff outside of entities directly in the DB, you can either refresh entities or clear the session.